# Fabric Crashlytics for android - how to include additional info in stackTrace area

Tags: android, twitter-fabric, crashlytics-android

I would like to get a object dump additionally sent during a crashlytics exception logging.  So for example lets say there is a nullPointerException that occurs. i'd like to additionally add a large object which would be my model and include that in the stack trace area in crashlytics. this way when i see the stacktrace i can also view the model information from the dump. How would i send this info in additional to the usual crashlytics logging ? Here is what i have so far:

```
        try{
    //....
throw new NullPointerException("my cool msg");

    }
          catch(Exception e){      
               Crashlytics.setInt("priority", 4);
                Crashlytics.setString("tag", "mytag");
                Crashlytics.setString("message", Model.toString());   
                Crashlytics.logException(e);         
    }
```

What is occuring now is that nothing is appearing. but if i comment out the setString for "message" then i get a stacktrace with the message "my cool msg".

UPDATE: I even tried Crashlytics.log(Model.toString()); but that shows nothing on crashlytics. i am setting up crashlytics from Application subclass in onCreate like this:  `Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());`

from the cashlytics docs i found this:

> To make sure that sending crash reports has the smallest impact on your user’s devices, Crashlytics logs have a maximum size of 64 KB. When a log exceeds 64 KB, the earliest logged values will be dropped in order to maintain this threshold.

this could be my issue. checking my size now...

adjusting the size of the payload did not work. i made the payload 9 characters but still its not appearing.

UPDATE:

Lets start again but more simply. why does the following not work for me ?

```
try{
//....
throw new NullPointerException("my cool msg");

}
   catch(Exception e){      
        Crashlytics.setInt("priority", 4);
         Crashlytics.setString("tag", "mytag");
         Crashlytics.setString("message", "");   
         Crashlytics.logException(e);         
}
```

What happens here is indeed a stacktrace appears in crasylytics dashboard with the words "my cool message" but there is nothing about priority, tag or message. Only the stacktrace is appearing.  should there
not be entries there with these headings or something ?

Comment: Not sure but if your Model is null then what message should except other than NULL? Also, try out by this way Crashlytics.log(Model.toString()); if it contains any data.

Comment: i confirmed it has data. i print it out in a toast message.

Comment: Did you try 2nd way?

Comment: yes, it does not work. i updated my response. i tried the following also but nothing gets sent to crashlytics. seems only works if i do not send the object .    Crashlytics.setInt("priority", 4);
                    Crashlytics.setString("tag", "tag_welcomeLogin");
                    //Crashlytics.setString("message", e.getMessage() + schemaStr);
                    Crashlytics.log(schemaStr.substring(1,90));
                    Crashlytics.logException(e); notice i even made the object 90 characters incase length was issue.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

AFter clicking on the green "view all sessions" button i was able to see the custom information. they could have made it more obvious.

and also from the [docs](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/caught-exceptions.html?caught%20exceptions#caught-exceptions) it seems the non-fatal exceptions are batched and sent the next time the app launches:

> Crashlytics processes exceptions on a dedicated background thread, so the performance impact to your app is minimal. To reduce your users’ network traffic, Crashlytics batches logged exceptions together and sends them the next time the app launches.